# How to change visited node color in Treepanel in Extjs like we have in html

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, nodes, treepanel

I am trying to change the color of visited node in Tree panel. I ma able to change the color and style of selected node and on doing mouse hover using below CSS: `.x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn:hover { }`

```
.x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn
```

Can any one please help me how to change visited node color like we have in html link.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an idea, but no final implementation.

What you need is an additional boolean field in the store, which stores whether the node has been visited or not:

```
name:"hasBeenVisited",
type:"bool",
defaultValue:false,
persist:false
```

In the grid, you need the `RowModel` selection model and have to bind to the select event of that selection model and tell the record that it has been visited:

```
select:function(selModel, record) {
    record.set("hasBeenVisited",true);
}
```

In the grid, you add a getRowClass function:

```
viewConfig:{
    getRowClass:function(record) {
        return record.get("hasBeenVisited")?"hasBeenVisitedCls":"";
    }
}
```

and then you have to add to your CSS a special color:

```
.hasBeenVisitedCls .x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn {
    color:purple
}
```